# Irregular DOM Parsing in php

Tags: php, dom, domparser

DOM parsing in php works only if the HTML is perfectly tagged. I need to parse html which is not a perfect DOM. And that HTML is from remote server so i can't change it.

```
<html>
 <body>
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td>
    1
    </td>
    <td>
    2
    </td></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

when i parse html with this structure it gives an error. `Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: Unexpected end tag : td in Entity, line: 173 in C:\wamp\wwwxxxxxx on line 51`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tools such as [`tidy`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/tidy.html.php) should be able to repair the HTML so you can use it in DOM.

```
$html = "<html>
 <body>
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td>
    1
    </td>
    <td>
    2
    </td></td>
   </tr>
</table>";

$tidy = tidy_parse_string($html);

$html = $tidy->html();
$cleanHTML = $html->value;
$doc = new DomDocument();
$doc-> loadhtml($cleanHTML);
```

Note: Tidy is not shipped with PHP, you would have to install the extension to use the functions